# C language: Copying strings one by one to an array

Tags: c, arrays, string, copy

I have been trying for hours to try and make this work, but the result was always the same-error and program not responding.

This file represents chat history and I select the username from every line. Now I want to add them into an array, so that I can later on count them for example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char const* const fileName = argv[1]; 
    FILE* file = fopen("beispielhafteGeschichte3", "r"); 
    char line[256];

    int i, j, k;
    char new_array[15][30];


    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) 
    {
     for (i=0; i<strlen(line); i++)
     {
        if (line[i-1]==']')
           {
             for(k=i; k<strlen(line); k++)
                {
                 printf("%c", line[k]);
                 if (line[k+1]==':') break;
                }
             strncpy(new_array[i], line[k], 29);  // ?????  
             printf("\n");
           }
     }
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

How to fix strncpy?

Comment: `strcpy` is fine; the fault is in your code.

Comment: Is there any reason you're checking outside the array in `if (line[i-1]==']')`? (i starts with 0)

Comment: but without it, it all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0; i<strlen(line); i++)
{
    if (line[i-1]==']')
```

The first time through the loop, `i` will be zero and you'll attempt to access `line[-1]` which invokes **undefined behaviour**

Comment: Yes, i know. But when i list the usernames, they all start with ']'.

Comment: i tried then to write it i-1, and it was all perfect

Answer (score 0):

line[k] is a char type, while the prototype for the strncpy function is:

```
char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
```

You should try edit your code like this:

```
strncpy(new_array[i], line+k, 29);
```